# Even if there is more than one space it should be replaced by only four slashes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am parsing html page now any of string comes from html page I want to seprate each word with some seprator like if string comes from html page  `FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0` and I want the string like `////FUTIDX////26FEB2009////NIFTY////0`.

In short any of string is there I want to insert  `////`  for each word in the string.

`I have tried str.Replace(" ","΄////")` but if I insert with string `FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0` it gives the result like `///////FUTIDX////26FEB2009////NIFTY 0///////` but I want like `////FUTIDX////26FEB2009////NIFTY 0////` means at each place where there is spaces I want to replace `"////"` but if there is more space between words then also there should be `"////"`,only four slaces not more than four.How should I do that ?

Comment: sounds like a task for regular expressions

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/434864-how-extract-words-out-string might help as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", "////")
```

Comment: We don't know whether he wants to replace tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a regular expression:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @" +", "////");
```

Comment: Yes I want to replace everything space,tabs which is non-human readeble.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to convert all double spaces to single in a loop until no more double spaces are left, THEN convert your single space to your "////" instances

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, with the matching pattern being '( )+' (i.e. one or more spaces) and the replacement pattern being the 4 slashes.